# ec2.py ec2.ini inventory pull on ec2 instance on a private subnet

Tags: amazon-ec2, private, inventory, subnet, ansible-inventory

I have the following on my AWS
1 vpc
3 subnets - 1 public , 2 private
1 internet gateway
1 nat instance
1 ec2 instance in public subnet
1 ec2 instance (for DB) in private subnet

With routing tables set and all instance running

I ran my ec2.py  to pull my inventory and I saw that **I dont have details of my ec2 instance from my private subnet**
any idea why ? 
I thought its my IAM role I am using. but I did give admin access to that role.

in my Ec2.ini I have the following
destination_variable = public_dns_name
vpc_destination_variable = private_ip_address

I did try private_dns_name and ip_address

Answer (score 0):

Actually it worked
the following combination pulled all the ec2 instances.
destination_variable = public_dns_name 
vpc_destination_variable = private_ip_address